# How to get the id value of a multiple SELECTION using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the ID values of **multiple selection list**. The multiple selection list 
is **generated dynamically**. How to get that values? If i can able to get the values means,
can I **convert it to JSON** object or, it ll be obtained as JSON object!!!!

Here is my code to generate it dynamically.

```
function displayMultipleList() {
    EmployeeManagement.getResponseList(function (respList) {
        var respOptionsSelect = document.getElementById('respOptions');
        var searchOptions = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < respList.length; i++) {
            var resp = respList[i];
            selectOptions = document.createElement('option');
            selectOptions.value = resp.respID;
            selectOptions.innerHTML = resp.respName;
            respOptionsSelect.appendChild(selectOptions);
        }


    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you really using JQuery?... or it is just a TAG?

Comment: I agree with the sentiment from Garis here. I see no jQuery here when it could easily be used to simplify the OP's code (and possibly even speed it up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the ambiguity of the question as a challenge, here are two options.

You're asking "how to get the values" and "convert it to JSON object." Taking that literally, and ignoring the mention of `id`, you can simply do this:

```
var x = JSON.stringify( $('#respOptions').val() );
```

...which will give you a simple (JSON) array of the selected values:

```
["somevalue","anothervalue"]
```

But if by "get the ID values" you mean "get the IDs and values of selected options", then you can do something like this:

```
var y = $('#respOptions option:selected').map( function(i,el){
    var result = {};
    result[ el.id ] = $(el).val();
    return result;
}).get();
y = JSON.stringify(y);
```

...which will give you an array like this:

```
[{"id1":"somevalue"},{"id5":"anothervalue"}]
```

I threw together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3UEr/1/) that makes assumptions about your HTML, and mocks in the `respList` from which the options are dynamically added. It solves the problem both ways.

If your browser doesn't support JSON.stringify, you can use Crockford's oft-recommended [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `serializeArray()` [function](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

`$("#respOptions").serializeArray()`

It will return to you the selected objects in a JavaScript array which can be easily stringified to a JSON string.

If your `<select>` element looks like this (don't forget the `name` attribute, as serializeArray needs it!):

```
<select name="respOptions" id="respOptions" multiple="true">
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

If items 2 and 3 were selected, you would get this back from the function:

```
[{ name: "respOptions", value: "2"}, {name: "respOptions", value: "3"}]
```

**EDIT** - I forgot to add the `name` attribute to the `<select>` element.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Good answer, D. However, I think it's important to point out that the OP said, "I want to get the ID values of multiple selection list." Excruciatingly vague, sure, but I suspect he meant the value of the ID attribute as opposed to simply the values. Regardless, glad you posted this so as to cover all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you iterate over a list of options inside a select element and get the ids:

http://jsfiddle.net/bXUhv/

In short:

```
$('option', $('#optionlist')).each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});​
```

With regard to converting any data into a JSON object, please look into [this jQuery library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple select and If you want the id in a array format
fiddle [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/kingleroyg/kwrhoLrh/)

```
var countries = [];
$.each($(".country option:selected"), function() {
  countries.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
alert(countries.join(", "));
```